# Filtering Redis hash entries - Delete entry from hash or from set

Tags: redis

I want to make a system that will redirect http clients depending on their source site and country.
To decide where to redirect them I have a list of rules. One rule can look like this:

```
"id":               1,
"sourceSites":      [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ],
"countries":        [ "US", "UK", "DE" ],
"amount":           1000,
"url":              "http://www.buyer2-url1.com"
```

There can be several hundred of such rules.

To store each rule I'm planning to use a Redis Hashes:
rule: amount  url

When a visitor comes in to the system I want to filter rules by sourceSite and by country of a visitor.
To implement a filter I'm planning to create index of sourceSites and countries using Redis Sets:

```
sourceSite:<sourceSiteID> rule:<id1> rule:<id2> ...
country:<countryCode> rule:<id1> rule:<id2> ...
```

When I have a visitor from country=UK and from sourceSiteID=5 I just make intersection of two sets:

```
SINTER sourceSite:5 country:UK
```

What I don't understand is what should I do when I need to delete a rule (for example, when the amount of traffic exceeds the necessary amount for the rule)?

Should I recreate all my Sets to make a new index of sourceSites and countries? But what if a visitor comes when an index is not yet ready?

Or I need to store another two sets for every rule with the list of sourceSites and a list of countries, so I could find all Sets of the index and remove a rule from them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably implement the second option and guarantee the consistency by using Redis transactions.

Adding a rule would be:

```
MULTI
HMSET rule:1 id 1 amount 1000 url http://www.buyer2-url1.com
SADD rule:1:sourceSites 1 2 3 4
SADD rule:1:countries US UK DE
SADD sourceSite:1 1
SADD sourceSite:2 1
SADD sourceSite:3 1
SADD sourceSite:4 1
SADD country:US 1
SADD country:UK 1
SADD country:DE 1
EXEC
```

Removing a rule would be:

```
WATCH rule:1
HGETALL rule:1
SMEMBERS rule:1:sourceSites
SMEMBERS rule:1:countries
MULTI
... sanity check depending on the content of the rule ...
For all source sites S (in rule:1:sourceSites):
   SREM sourceSite:S 1
For all country codes C (in rule:1:countries):
   SREM country:C 1
DEL rule:1:countries
DEL rule:1:sourceSites
DEL rule:1
EXEC
```

It is better to use only integers in sets (do not prefix them by rule:), so that Redis can apply memory optimizations. Also, consider using pipelining to reduce the number of required roundtrips.